# How to convert Assets Images & Icons to PdfImage in flutter using dart_pdf

Tags: pdf, flutter, dart, pdf-generation, flutter-layout

[Used Library: dart_pdf](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf) After searching I found the same issue in [GITHUB](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/15) but unable to resolve the issue. I tried this but blurry image appears. Please help!!

```
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/test.jpg');
  var codec = await instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();

  var imageBytes = await frame.image.toByteData();
  PdfImage assetImage = PdfImage(pdf.document,
      image: imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List(), width: 86, height: 80);
```

**Rendered Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this instead:

```dart
final PdfImage assetImage = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
    pdf: pdf.document, 
    image: const AssetImage('assets/test.jpg'),
);
```

Comment: One more question: Which one will render fast in pdf-file  SVG or PNG images ?

Comment: If you first raster the SVG to an Image object, then it will be an image, exactly like the PNG. So you have only the conversion impact, the resulting Pdf file will be the same. You can also use a Jpeg image directly with PdfImage.jpeg() which is faster because there is no conversion involved: the Jpeg file is directly embedded inside the Pdf. PNG images, on the other hand, will be recompressed as native Pdf bitmap.

Comment: where is this method pdfImageFromImageProvider come from?

Comment: in flutter 2 I am not able to find ant more pdfImageFromImageProvider in pdf library. https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/31

Answer (score 5):

This function will create your pdf with image and custom data

```
 var pdf = new pw.Document();

 Future<pw.Document> createPDF() async {
    var assetImage = pw.MemoryImage(
      (await rootBundle.load('assets/images/delivery.png'))
          .buffer
          .asUint8List(),
    );

    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          var width = MediaQuery.of(this.context).size.width;
          var height = MediaQuery.of(this.context).size.height;
          return pw.Container(
            margin: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.1),
            child: pw.ListView(
              children: [
                // your image here
                pw.Container(
                    height: height * 0.25, child: pw.Image(assetImage)),
              // other contents
                pw.Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    pw.Text("order Id:"),
                    pw.Text(widget.doc['orderId']),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }));
        
    return pdf;
  }
```

use this function to save

```
 Future savePdf(pw.Document pdfnew) async {
    String pdfName;
    File file;

    try {
      
      var documentDirectory = await AndroidPathProvider.downloadsPath; // for android downloads folder
    //  var localDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // for local directory
    
      setState(() {
        pdfName = "your_pdf_name";
      });
  
      file = File("$documentDirectory/$pdfName.pdf");
      await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
   
      return file.path;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answers worked for me