# How to convert image to pdf using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have implemented a app to capture images using camera and display captured image in new page as a Image but I want to display the captured Image(ex:document) as Pdf file(editable).

So how can I convert my image(ex:document) as a pdf file ?

```
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896905/how-to-convert-assets-images-icons-to-pdfimage-in-flutter-using-dart-pdf

Comment: You can use https://pdf-lib.js.org/ to export as pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This flutter printing library](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) talks about `To load an image from an ImageProvider:` perhaps this might do what you ask, you might be able to extract the PDF after its processed the image

Answer (score 0):

You can convert image file to pdf with package `pdf: ^3.8.4`

Store all your images in Uint8List `List<Uint8List> imagesUint8list = [];`

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

var pdf = pw.Document();
String pdfFile = '';

createPdfFile() async {
final List<pw.Widget> pdfImages = imagesUint8list.map((image) {
  return pw.Padding(
      padding: pw.EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
      child: pw.Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            pw.Text(
                'Page'
                    ' ' +
                    (imagesUint8list
                        .indexWhere((element) => element == image) +
                        1)
                        .toString(),
                style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            pw.SizedBox(height: 12),
            pw.Image(
                pw.MemoryImage(
                  image,
                ),
                height: 600,
                fit: pw.BoxFit.fitHeight)
          ]));
}).toList();

//create PDF
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
    margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(10),
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return <pw.Widget>[
        pw.Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              pw.Text(AppStringConst.studentAnswerSheet,
                  textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
                  style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 26)),
              pw.Divider(),
            ]),
        pw.Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: pw.MainAxisSize.max,
            children: pdfImages),
      ];
    }));
```

}