# Reduce the image size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to reduce the image selected from gallery size from MB to KB enter by the use. How can I do that?
I want a textbox in which the user can enter the value to reduce the size and after pressing a button
the images are resizer

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) which provides various functions for image manipulation, resizing, cropping and much more.

Take a look at code usage examples at [this page](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples).

You should be able to resize image for given ressolution, with proper calculations you could be able to resize it into given size also.

Comment: i have used this but i want to implement it dynamically

Comment: do you have code example what did you create and how dynamically you want to use it?

Comment: can you say me that how to convert multiple images to pdf file in flutter please

Comment: Check this question it may give you answer to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091269/how-to-convert-image-to-pdf-using-flutter

Comment: i have used https://pub.dev/packages/printing this library but it selects only one image I want to select multiple image

Answer (score 0):

[**flutter_image_compress**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) Plugin provides the functionality to compress image size and weight

See Full [Example on Github](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_image_compress/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: can you say me that how to convert multiple images to pdf file in flutter please

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) Library then you can directly use something like this. This is useful if you want to save it in Firebase or similar backend.

```
    ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile compressedImage = await imagePicker.getImage(
         source: ImageSource.camera,
         imageQuality:70, // depending on compression ratio
        );
```

Else if you want to use it only for compression then you can use [Flutter Image Compression.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

To convert png(Image File) to PDF, you can use this [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf).

Comment: can you say me that how to convert multiple images to pdf file in flutter please

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package called to crop and resize `ImageCropper` and `flutter image compress`  .
It allows you to crop and resize the image to any or specified aspect ratio you want and can even compress the image.
Here is the link,

1.Image cropper https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper

2.flutter image compress https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress