# how to print image via printer from flutter desktop app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

image is not printing(in printer) from desktop app flutter. How can I print image using printer?

image should be print in printer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert you image file to .pdf file with help of
pdf: ^3.8.4 [How to convert image to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76064488/21581958)

Then use library `printing 5.10.3` to tringger printer

This plugin allows Flutter apps to generate and print documents

after that you can directly share your pdf file to any printing device `await Printing.sharePdf(bytes: await doc.save(), filename: 'my-document.pdf');`

[Refer this link to check out more about this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

Comment: I am using same package priniting. Cant we directly print images without converting to pdf?

Comment: It is the best answer I would come up with, I think to tigger a printer you need a document and for that it should converted before in pdf. Accept this as your answer if it helps you. Thank you