# How to add a png image in flutter, while we are creating a pdf?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the library pdf https://pub.dev/packages/pdf to create a pdf.
How to add an image, which is in the form of png in the pdf sceen?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widget/Image-class.html. This is a well written package. All pdf-widget behave exactly as flutter-widgets.

Comment: @Doc Image expects only pdf image as a parameter, I've png image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896905/how-to-convert-assets-images-icons-to-pdfimage-in-flutter-using-dart-pdf

Answer (score 0):

as in decoumentaion of the plugin you use

To load an image from a file:

```
final image = PdfImage.file(
pdf.document,
bytes: File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync(),
);

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
build: (pw.Context context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(image),
  ); // Center
})); // Page
```